# Android Gradle error occurs

Tags: android

> ```
> Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version,
>   or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to 
>  "f4a0bcdad02706f1af97b485d6a6a0c5e7d9a560". Fix plugin version and sync project
> ```

---

**build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update your Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
 }
```

---

**Also Your Gradle version**

```
//You Used Above Version Also

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Comment: but my classpath is    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

Comment: It's nice.. You can update only the appcompat and recyclerview as Shown in answer

Answer (score 0):

its because your `gradle` plugin is too old, you need to update it to latest version.

Download the latest `Gradle` from [here](https://gradle.org/downloads)

You will need run sdk manager and check for updated revisions.

In Project level `build.gradle`:

Replace:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
```

with:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

and in the app level `build.gradle` which you have posted above:

Replace:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

With:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

Comment: my classpath is    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

Comment: have you tried my solution? just update it to the one i have given it will solve your problem.